# Using eval to perform a mathematical operation

Tags: python, built-in

In the code below the line of code  `prod = eval("beg1" "operation" "beg2")` doesn't work! If anyone could give me some help I would gratefully appreciate it!

```
def quiz():

    global tally

    tally = 0
    questions = 10

    name = input("What is your surname name")

    form = input("What is your form")




    for i in range(questions):
            ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
            operation = random.choice(ops)
            beg1 = random.randint(1, 10)
            beg2 = random.randint(1, 10)
            prod = eval("beg1" "operation" "beg2")
            print (prod)

            begAns = input("What is " + str(beg1)+ operation + str(beg2) + "? ")

            if int(begAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                tally += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)



    print ("Your score was", tally, "out of 10")
```

Comment: What on earth were you expecting it to do?!

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out, use string concatenation with `+` to put the value of the `operation` variable into the string that gets `eval`ed:

```
prod = eval(str(beg1) + operation + str(beg2))
```

Otherwise the program is trying to `eval` the literal string `"operation"` (it's like typing e.g. `1operation4` into the python interpreter).

However, I'd encourage you to not use `eval` at all. Instead, make a list of operator functions (from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html) module) and then apply it to the two random ints:

```
import operator
op_names = {operator.add:'+', operator.sub:'-', operator.mul:'*',
            operator.floordiv:'/'}
ops = list(op_names.keys())
operation = random.choice(ops)
beg1 = random.randint(1, 10)
beg2 = random.randint(1, 10)
prod = operation(beg1, beg2)
print('What is {0} {1} {2}?'.format(beg1, op_names[operation], beg2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this dddsnn!! Very helpful indeed! The only problem I have now is actually displaying the operator in the print statement which asks the user the question.begAns = input("What is " + str(beg1) + (operation) + str(beg2) + "? ")

Comment: Thanks a lot for this dddsnn!! Very helpful indeed! The only problem I have now is actually displaying the operator in the print statement which asks the user the question.                                                              begAns = input("What is " + str(beg1) + (str(operation)) + str(beg2) + "? ")                                                                                                                                                                                                                               I want to display +/*or- and not What is 5<built-in function mul>2?

Comment: Right, forgot about that. I'd say the best thing would be to make a dictionary mapping names to functions. I'll edit it into the answer.